React Firebase Anonymous Login
I am using React Firebase to login anonymously as well as Realtime Database to add the user profile to the DB. Upon first login, user is logged in correctly and user profile is created. When I log out, and try to login right-away I'm getting the alert ""user does not exist", however the user is still created in the DB and logged in. If I log out and then refresh the page before logging back in, then the alert does not appear.
When I look at my logs, upon the first login i see the following:
user added successfully
user signed in
user auth

However, after logging out and logging back in the second time I see the following, which is incorrect:
user auth
user added successfully
user signed in

I realize it is likely related to the async behaviour but I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong? Is the alert("user does not exist") in the try block even necessary?
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "./firebase";
import { onAuthStateChanged, signInAnonymously } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ref, get, set } from "firebase/database";

const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const anonLogin = async (event) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await signInAnonymously(auth);

      await handleAddUserToDb(auth.currentUser.uid);

      navigate("/home");
      console.log("user signed in");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during anonymous login:", error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }

    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    try {
      await auth.signOut();
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleAddUserToDb = async (uid) => {
    const userRef = ref(db, `users/${uid}`);

    const newUser = {
      id: uid,
      name: "Guest",
    };

    try {
      await set(userRef, newUser);
      console.log("user added successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error adding user to database:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user.uid);
        setLoading(false);
        await fetchUserProfile(user.uid);

        console.log("user auth");
      } else {
        console.log("user logged out", user);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const fetchUserProfile = async (id) => {
    const userRef = ref(db, `users/${id}`);

    try {
      const snapshot = await get(userRef);
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        setUserProfile(snapshot.val());
      } else {
        alert("user does not exist");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        loading,
        setLoading,
        anonLogin,
        userProfile,
        logout,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useUser = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};




It seems that the code in your onAuthStateChanged callback and your code after signInAnonymously are getting in each other's way. I recommend setting a breakpoint on each line of these code blocks, running in the debugger, and checking what happens.
